# How can I set the value of log_line_prefix while creating postgres rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cloudformation

I am creating a postgres database in aws cloud through CFT. I want to set log_line_prefix value in the postgres.conf file.I am unable to set the values by adding it to db parameter group.Is there any other way to set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a log analyzer such as pgbadger to analyze PostgreSQL logs. The pgbadger documentation states that the %l pattern (log line for session/process) should be a part of the prefix. However, if you provide the current rds log_line_prefix as a parameter to pgbadger it should still produce a report.

Answer (score 3):

log_line_prefix isn't supported in RDS, Here is the workaround mentioned in the official documentation.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Badger